# DataReader.Read() only returns one value

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, ado.net

I am trying to retrieve data from a MYSQL table that has 2 rows but, only the first row is returned. The SQL statement used is very simple sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM table"

With the code below the class only returns the first value found

```
    private ArrayList dbRead(String sqlQuery, String classQuery)
    {
        ArrayList dbCategoryResults = new ArrayList();

    // *** CONNECT TO DATABASE
        Console.WriteLine("** Database Connection: Connecting to database");
        MySqlConnection dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(dbStringConnection);

        try
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("** Database Connection: Connected to database server");

            // *** READ FROM DATABASE
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, dbConnection);
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (dataReader.Read())
            {
                if (classQuery == "categories")
                {
                    //String det = dataReader[1].ToString();

                    dbCategoryResults.Add(dataReader[1]);

                    Console.WriteLine("Found " + dbCategoryResults.Count);

                    return dbCategoryResults;
                }
            }
            dataReader.Close();

            command.Dispose();
            dbConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Database Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        // CLOSE DATABASE
        try
        {
            dbConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: The documentation [MySqlDataReader.Read Method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader_Read.htm) **Advances the MySqlDataReader to the next record.**

Comment: To amplify what @TheGeneral said: you need a `while` loop surrounding that call

Comment: replaced the if(datareader.read()) to while but still same problem

`while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                if (classQuery == "categories")
                {
                    //String det = dataReader[1].ToString();

                    dbCategoryResults.Add(dataReader[1]);

                    Console.WriteLine("Found " + dbCategoryResults.Count);

                    return dbCategoryResults;
                }
            }`

Comment: Replaced with `while` what exactly? Please update the question with the current code. You've either used `while` incorrectly or there is only one row.

Comment: **[Using the Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: Unrelated tips: `MySqlConnection`, `MySqlCommand` and `MySqlDataReader` are all `IDisposable` so should each be in a `using` block. Once you've done that you can remove all the calls to Close and Dispose.

Answer (score 5):

Its as simple as

```
// Always call Read before accessing data.
// Advances the MySqlDataReader to the next record.
// returns true if it finds a record
while (dataReader.Read()) 
{
   // depending on your query
   Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetInt32(0) + ", " + myReader.GetString(1));
}
```

if you want the number of rows you could always make use of a `DataTable` or even just use a count in the while loop. DataTable Example :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);

Console.WriteLine("Rows returned : " + dt.Rows.Count); 

foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
     Console.WriteLine(dr["SomeResultingColumn"]);
}
```